# Suggestions for building a Rules Engine

Tags: scripting, cross-platform, interpreter, dsl, rule-engine

We have a forms engine that allows users to build out various form templates.  The next iteration requires a feature to allow users to construct *rules* within the form builder.

It essentially simplifies down to a boolean interpreter.  Where users define rules across form fields to affect other form fields.  This is powerful for full form dynamic validation.

An *optional* nice-to-have would be to have this rules engine execute on iOS, Android, and web (Java).

What I don't want is to write another DSL.

So I'm reaching out to gauge other people's experience with perhaps a cross-platform Rules Engine Library that they might have encountered or been part of a similar challenge.